# Dataset division by dataset subtotals

Tags: dataset

I have the following dataset:

```
dataset = Dataset[
  {
   <|"Year" -> 1, 
    "Dataset" ->
     <|
      
      "a" -> <|"x" -> 2559014, "y" -> 756672|>,
      "b" -> <|"x" -> 620783, "y" -> 550642|>,
      "c" -> <|"x" -> 91468, "y" -> 129662|>
      |>
    |>,
   <|"Year" -> 2, 
    "Dataset" ->
     <|
      
      "a" -> <|"x" -> 2693402, "y" -> 766245|>,
      "b" -> <|"x" -> 598006, "y" -> 478835|>,
      "c" -> <|"x" -> 161606, "y" -> 165458|>
      |>
    |>,
   <|"Year" -> 3, 
    "Dataset" ->
     <|
      
      "a" -> <|"x" -> 2757333, "y" -> 791200|>,
      "b" -> <|"x" -> 582524, "y" -> 483263|>,
      "c" -> <|"x" -> 167925, "y" -> 135506|>
      |>
    |>
   }
  ]
```

I would like to divide the individual "x" and "y" values for each "a", "b", and "c" for each "Year" by the totals I get across the "a", "b", and "c" grouping.

I know I can get the total across the "a", "b", and "c" grouping by using:

```
dataset[All, All, Total, All]
```

but I don't know how to divide in the way that I want. The manual result would look like the following:

````
dataset = Dataset[
  {
   <|"Year" -> 1, 
    "Dataset" ->
     <|
      
      "a" -> <|"x" -> 2559014/3271265, "y" -> 756672/1436976|>,
      "b" -> <|"x" -> 620783/3271265, "y" -> 550642/1436976|>,
      "c" -> <|"x" -> 91468/3271265, 
        "y" -> 129662/1436976|>
      |>
    |>,
   <|"Year" -> 2, 
    "Dataset" ->
     <|
      
      "a" -> <|"x" -> 2693402/3453014, "y" -> 766245/1410538|>,
      "b" -> <|"x" -> 598006/3453014, "y" -> 478835/1410538|>,
      "c" -> <|"x" -> 161606/3453014, 
        "y" -> 165458/1410538|>
      |>
    |>,
   <|"Year" -> 3, 
    "Dataset" ->
     <|
      
      "a" -> <|"x" -> 2757333/3507782, "y" -> 791200/1409969|>,
      "b" -> <|"x" -> 582524/3507782, "y" -> 483263/1409969|>,
      "c" -> <|"x" -> 167925/3507782, 
        "y" -> 135506/1409969|>
      |>
    |>
   }
  ]
```
````

Comment: Note that `dataset[ All, All, Total ]` suffices to get totals across "a", "b", "c" (at least in `v12.3.1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html).

With

```
total = dataset[All, All, Total]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

then

```
MapIndexed[
 {val, index} |-> val/total[Sequence @@ Delete[index, 3]]
 , dataset
 , {4}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The mapping targets elements at level 4 only. Since `total` has aggregated over the third key of `dataset` then the third key of `index` is removed to reference the total.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here, as commented above, `total = dataset[ All, All, Total ]` will suffice.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way that uses query operators and functional style:

```
dataset[
  All
, {"Dataset" -> {Total/*Curry[Divide], All} /* Apply[Map]}
]
```

[image: Dataset]

Note: `Curry` is deprecated in favour of `OperatorApplied` in the most recent versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Will take a closer look at this. Thanks.